# Returning the result of celery task to the client in Django template

Tags: django, redis, django-celery

So I'm trying to accomplish the following. User browses webpage and at the sime time there is a task running in the background. When the task completes it should return `args` where one of `args` is `flag: True` in order to trigger a javascript and javascript shows a modal form.

I tested it before without async tasks and it works, but now with celery it just stores results in database. I did some research on tornado-celery and related stuff but some of components like tornado-redis is not mantained anymore so it would not be vise in my opinion to use that.

So what are my options, thanks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you want to communicate something from the server side back to the client. You generally have three options for that:

1) Make a long pending request to the server - kinda bad. Jumping over the details, it will bog down your web server if not configured to handle that, it will make your site score low on performance tests and if the request fails, everything fails.
2) Poll the server with numerous requests with a time interval (0.2 s, something like that) - better. It will increase the traffic, but the requests will be tiny and will not interfere with the site's performance very much. If you instate a long interval to not load the server with pointless requests, then the users will see the data with a bit of a delay. On the upside this will not fail (if written correctly) even if the connection is interrupted.
3) Websockets where the server can just hit the client with any message whenever needed - nice, but takes some time to get used to. If you want to try, you can use `django-channels` which is a nice library for Django websockets.

If I did not understand you correctly and this is not the problem at hand and you are figuring how to get data back from a Celery task to Django, then you can store the Celery task ID-s and use the ID-s to first check, if the task is completed and then query the data from Celery.

Comment: So I tryed `django-channels` and sync and asyn tasks worked fine but when I tryed to make a backround task with worker it raised an error on `from channels import Channel`. A quick search and I found out that the same goes for Group import. This could be a bug since the info I found was couple days old. So I went back to celery and now I'm trying to implement yore last advice with `task_id`.